# How to install Mysql 5.0.29 in Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I downloaded the zip file for Mysql 5.0.29, but there is no .exe file in the folder. No idea how to install it in Windows.

All the instructions online are saying to click a .exe file to start installation.

Can anyone help me a bit? Many thanks!

Comment: Download MSI file and run on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/installing.html#windows-install-archive

Here are instructions to install MySQL on windows, alternatively you can download MSI Installer and install on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could get it done easily by a bit googling, just download the .msi file which you want from [mysql site](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/)

[Follow these simple steps and get it done](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-mysql-windows-7.php)

Hope this helps.